# InlineShapes exported as image add border

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using below code for saving MS Word images and converting into base64.

When exporting the image it adds some borders.
Original Image
[image]

after export
[image: imag2]

```vb
If singleline.Range.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
    Dim shp1 As InlineShape
    Dim mchart1 As Shape
    Set shp1 = singleline.Range.InlineShapes(1)
    shp1.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Set mchart1 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddChart(xl3DAreaStacked, , , shp1.Width, shp1.Height)
    mchart1.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit
    mchart1.Chart.Paste
    mchart1.Chart.Export ("c:\here\" + CStr(i) + ".png")
    mchart1.Chart.Delete
    b64strng = ConvertFileToBase64("c:\here\" + CStr(i) + ".png")
    Kill "c:\here\" + CStr(i) + ".png"
End If
```

Is there any fix or Alternative to export images?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difference between your screenshots, possibly because of the dark browser background. Is the border visible after the **Export** command, or after the **ConvertFileToBase64** function?

It appears you're trying to export a non-chart graphic by using a chart kludge. You'll get better results by enlisting PowerPoint to do the graphics export. Here's a sample macro that shows how to export Word graphics from PowerPoint. You can modify this to export a single Shape or ShapeRange (your graphic) instead of a complete slide.

```
Public Sub ExportMap()
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShapeRange As PowerPoint.ShapeRange
Dim Path$, File$
Dim oRange As Range


  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdAllowOnlyFormFields Then
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect
  End If
  myDate$ = Format(Date, "m-d-yyyy")
  Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
  Path$ = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator
  File$ = "WorldMap " & myDate$ & ".png"
  Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add(msoFalse)
  
  Set oRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("WholeMap").Range
  oRange.CopyAsPicture
  
  Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
  On Error Resume Next
  With pptPres.PageSetup
    .SlideSize = 7
    .SlideWidth = 1150
    .SlideHeight = 590
  End With
  Set pptShapeRange = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, Link:=msoFalse)
  With pptShapeRange
    .Top = .Top + 6
'    .Left = .Left + 510
  End With
  
  pptSlide.Export Path$ & File$, "PNG"
  
  pptApp.Quit
  
  Set pptPres = Nothing
  Set pptApp = Nothing
  Set pptSlide = Nothing
  If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
    ActiveDocument.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, noreset:=True
  End If
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox "All done! Check the folder containing this template for a file called '" & File$ & "'."
End Sub
```